Files arent being staged in nextflow
I have a simple pipeline:
process test1 {
    input:
      path a
    script:
    """
    ls ${a}
    """
}

workflow {
  file = file(params.a)
    test1(params.a)
}

when I run
touch test.txt
nextflow run test.nf --a test.txt

I get the error:
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'test1'

Caused by:
  Not a valid path value: 'test.txt'

I am not entirely sure why the file is not being staged even though it is present in the same directory where the pipeline is being run.
I tried using absolute paths, and that works, I tried using other files in the same directory and doesnt work, I would assume that this should run as is.


ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'test1'

Caused by:
  Not a valid path value: 'test.txt'


This is because params.a is a String, but the process is expecting a path value. Instead, use the file() method to pass in a filesystem object (i.e. a file). Note that the process input is implicitly wrapped in a value channel:
params.a = 'test.txt'


process test1 {

    debug true

    input:
    path a

    script:
    """
    ls ${a}
    """
}

workflow {

    my_file = file( params.a )

    test1( my_file )
}

Results:
$ nextflow run main.nf 

 N E X T F L O W   ~  version 24.04.4

Launching `main.nf` [maniac_albattani] DSL2 - revision: 75134ff125

executor >  local (1)
[31/25b733] process > test1 [100%] 1 of 1 ✔
test.txt


